# ASP.NET Forms Authentication not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

After clicking the login button i want to redirect to `add_customer.aspx` page but instead it comes back to the login page with ReturnUrl containing `add_customer.aspx`

Here is my code

**Web.config**

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name="ASPAUTH" protection="None" timeout="30" path="/"></forms>
   </authentication>
   <authorization>
      <deny users="?" /> 
   </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="logout.aspx">
    <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users ="*" />
    </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

**C# code:**

```
//After Validating User 
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(name,true);
bool test = Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
//shows false here on debugging
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
{
     string a = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"].ToString();
     if ( a != "/")
          Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
}
Response.Redirect("add_customer.aspx");
```

Comment: You've just created the ticket. You never set the cookie with the ticket, so the user does not appear logged in.

Comment: @dbugger Please if you could show me how to do that and,I tried doing the SetAuthCookie method but it it redirects me to the add_customer.aspx page but when i try to access any other page is takes me back to the login page

Comment: FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(name,true);
bool test = Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
it shows me false even though it is just the next line

Comment: That's because the user was NOT authenticated when the request was made.  It will be the next time a request is made with the cookie.

Comment: ya saw that in some post right after editing here, is was caused due to writing the FormsAuthentication.Signout() in master page i guess after i removed that is started working fine but although when i logout if i press back button on my browser it still allows me to access is but not when i manually enter the url

Comment: *if i press back button on my browser it still allows me to access* 99% change that the browser is *caching* the page....